# How to sort the Excel column numerically

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop

I want to sort a column which contains numeric numbers. In my column E, I have a column of numbers by they aren't sorted properly.

For example: 8, 2, 3, 1, 10

I want 1, 2, 3, 8, 10

Here is my code

```
    Excel.Range bRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "P1");
    bRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
    bRange.Sort(bRange.Columns[5], Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
```

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 8, 10 is an ascending order, not descending.

Comment: woops, my bad, thanks for point out

Comment: but it still doesn't work

Comment: What is the type of `bRange.Columns[5]`?

Comment: sorry codor, it should be bRange instead. Typo mistake

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
Excel.Range bRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "P1");
```

Is only selecting a single row, from A1 to P1. A row is a table with one entry so sorting it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is in the column "E", you can get them like:

```
Excel.Range bRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E1","E5");
```

And for sorting try this:

```
bRange.Sort(bRange.Columns[1, Type.Missing],Excel.XlSortOrder.xlAscending);
```